# Menu of header is not on the gray bar in IE

Tags: html, css

i have problems with IE8 :
http://immobilien.la-via.ch/

Website header is not on the right position.
If you open it in chrome or FF  it works.

2nd problem: white area is not 960 width....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly contain your content inside your `#nav` div, you can do that by triggering the hasLayout effect on it, like so:

```
#nav {
 zoom:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you mix table-design with div-based design? Just a recommendation: your layout can quite easily be designed with divs only (no tables). Cleaning your code up will help you a lot more than just fixing some issues that occur now in maybe IE8... have you seen your site in Safari/Chrome as well? And IE9+? Probably you should have a look, as you can see the consequences of your (sorry, it is not meant offensive, just nicely in order to help) messed up HTML code...

Also, don't apply a fixed height to a table/div if possible, as you probably want it to automatically adapt the height to the amount of text. You have some parts of your code where you use divs anyway already, just my recommendation would be to design the whole site on divs...